# Moving plot label

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am trying to place the plot title somewhere neat, to the left of x=0.

```
  Plot[1/(1 + Exp[-x]), {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Framed@Pane[
    "F (x)=\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(1 + \*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \
\(-x\)]\)]\)", Alignment -> Right]]
```

I tried this but it's still sticking at the top of figure, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Inset[]` to add it to the graphics, instead it being a label:

```
Plot[1/(1 + Exp[-x]), {x, -10, 10}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed@
    Pane["F (x)=\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(1 + \
\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(-x\)]\)]\)", Alignment -> Right],
   {-1.5, 1}, {1, 1}]]
```

[image]

FWIW, I rather prefer the look of `TraditionalForm` in this:

```
Plot[1/(1 + Exp[-x]), {x, -10, 10}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Framed@
    Pane[HoldForm[F[x] == 1/(1 + E^-x)], Alignment -> Right],
   {-1.5, 1}, {1, 1}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your label with another `Framed` with the options `FrameStyle -> None` and `FrameMargins -> {{0, rightmargin}, {0,0}}` with your choice of `rightmargin`:

```
Plot[1/(1 + Exp[-x]), {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLabel -> Framed[Framed[Pane[HoldForm[F[x] = 1/(1 + E^-x)], 
   Alignment -> Right]], 
   FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> {{0, Scaled[.1]}, {0, 0}}]]
```

[image]

Use `FrameMargins -> {{0, Scaled[.14]}, {0, Scaled[.05]}}` to get

[image]

**Update:** An alternative way is to put the label in a dynamic, *movable* `Epilog`:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = Scaled[{.5, 1}]},
 Plot[1/(1 + Exp[-x]), {x, -10, 10},
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Scaled[.05]}},
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Epilog -> Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt],
     Panel[HoldForm[F[x] = 1/(1 + E^-x)]],
     Background -> White, LocatorRegion -> Full]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the `TraditionalForm` unnecessary? (It's applied by default here, I think.)

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2; good point.